# Number Theory help required

Tags: number-theory

Hi, can someone help me solve this?

$$110x \equiv 3 \pmod{73}$$

So far, I have completed the the Magic table and found the GCD.
I got

```
    |1 |1 |1 |36
---------------
1 0 |1 |1 |2 |73
0 1 |1 |2 |3 |110
```

What should I do next?

How do I find $110^{-1} \pmod {73}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $110 \equiv 37$ (mod $73$) and $2*37=74 \equiv 1$ (mod $73$).

Comment: How did you get 37?

Comment: Well, because 110-73=

Comment: so 74 is the inverse correct?

Comment: No, 74 is the same as 1 modulo 73. So 2 and 37 are each other's inverses. So you only have to multiply your equation at both sides with 2. Clear now? Please tell me if you still do not grasp it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I'm unfamiliar with the magic table :(. But I will attempt to help you nonetheless.

First, it is always a good idea to reduce the numbers in the equation. So,
$$110x\equiv 3\mod 73 \quad\text{ becomes }\quad 37x\equiv3\mod73.$$

Now, we need to find $37^{-1}\mod 73$, which is the same as what you were trying to find ($110^{-1}$). To do so, we need to understand what it means to be the inverse of $37$.
The inverse is actually a "buddy" of $37$, it is a number such that 
$$37\times\text{inverse}\equiv 1\mod73.$$

Now, rearranging this, we have 
$$37\times\text{inverse}+73k=1,\quad\text{some } k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$

Does this look familiar to you? Hint: Euclid may show you the way here.

Comment: How did you get 37?

Comment: What is the remainder when you divide $110$ by $73$?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in a way more.

First of all, you must expanded $\frac{73}{110}$ in a continued fraction. We get $\frac{73}{110}=[0;1,1,1,36]$. Taking a convergent penultimate i.e. $[0;1,1,1]=\frac{2}{3}$. We know that property of continued fractions: $\dfrac{73}{110}-\dfrac{2}{3}=\dfrac{-1}{110\cdot 3}$. Multiplying both sides by $3\cdot 3 \cdot 110.$ We get: $3\cdot 3\cdot 73-3\cdot 2\cdot 110=-1\cdot 3.$ From here $110\cdot 6 \equiv 3 \pmod{73}$. So $x\equiv 6\pmod{73}.$ That's all.